# Delphi Mobile development (Android) - can't load deployed file

Tags: android, delphi, mobile

Dear enlightened ones,

I am trying to load a textfile from which I populate 3 client datasets. It is a mobile application in the making which I am just trying out on the android device. I seem to have trouble to load or find the deployed text files.

The text files I have deployed on the android in the remote **assets\internal** folder

I am currently testing this on my Nexus 5, and have no other device available for the moment.

The load code goes as follows:

```
  //Load Parts

  slParts := TStringList.Create;
  slPartsOutput := TStringList.Create;


   try
      slParts.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '/Parts.txt');
      cdsParts.DisableControls;
      cdsParts.Open;
      for iParts := 0 to (slParts.Count -1) do
       begin
         cdsParts.Append;
         split(#9,slParts[iParts],slPartsOutput);
         cdsPartsNumber.Value := slPartsOutput[2];
         cdsPartsName.Value := slPartsOutput[3];
         cdsPartsCategory.Value := slPartsOutput[1];
         cdsPartsWeight.Value := slPartsOutput[4];
         cdsPartsDimensions.Value := slPartsOutput[5];
         cdsParts.Post;
       end
     finally
      cdsParts.EnableControls;
     End ;
```

The curious thing is: it works fine when I compile this on my Windows 64-bit tool with the same code. Just it seems to have trouble loading it on the application. Where exactly can I find this "assets" folder on my device so I might check wether the files have been written? Is it that maybe I need to create a folder? If so, what code do I use to create a folder?

**The full error**

> Exception class EFOpenError with message 'Cannot open file "/data/data/com.embarcadero.MyProject/files/Parts.txt" No such file or directory' Process MyProject.apk

Edit:

I think it has to do with my phone itself. When trying to create an empty folder, it does not allow me to. I will try on the SD card and report back

Edit2:

I am still stuck. The files are not being deployed on either WIndows nor Android. No wonder the files cannot be read. I will investigate for further causes, but help is always welcome. :) (I am trying to deploy in my documents folder on Windows, without succes.)

Comment: `TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '/Parts.txt'` seems to have a `//` in it (PathDelim = /)

Comment: Have you deployed it to all configurations and try add \ to your remote folder. So it should be assets\internal\. Also delete PathDelim